# Merge changes from a separated repository

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on a code base in Git that has been disconnected from its original remote repository, and stood up under a new remote repository.  My team has performed enough work under this new repository that we have significantly diverged from the original repository's Git tracking history.

There is a team continually making updates to the original code base that my team occasionally needs to pull in to our separated code base.  Since the two code bases have been separated under different remote repositories my team cannot easily pull in any of these updates.

The only way we receive updates from the original team is by using physical CDs to transport the code onto our information system.  We can't use the Git tracking for these updates because our Git repository's history has diverged so drastically from the original code base.

I have tried creating a new Git branch from our repository, copying the received update files into this new branch and overwriting our files, and then merging this new branch back into our main branch.  But this doesn't work because Git sees the files in the new branch are newer than the files in our main branch and simply accepts every change from the new files and deletes the changes we've made.

The easiest method I have found to work so far is to copy the new files into our main branch (without committing anything), and use `git diff` to show the changes brought by the new files.  Then I use a text editor to manually merge any changes we want to take from the new files and commit to a branch that will be merged into our baseline.  This works, but since we're dealing with hundreds of files in an update this process can take days to confidently finish.

The closest questions I've found are fixed using the `--no-commit` or `--no-ff` flags, but neither of these address our core issue of needing to manually review every single difference and decide what to keep.

It's clear to me that Git wasn't built to handle this issue, I'm just hoping there's an option or feature I've overlooked that could help.

TL;DR

I need a way to merge two sets of identically named files containing different sets of updates from two separate repositories without one set clobbering the other using vanilla Git version 2.20.0.windows.1.  We also don't have access to other diff tools such as Beyond Compare or Ultra Compare (or this would be a non-issue).

Answer (score 0):

If you could get a complete copy of their working directory including .git folder, then you could add your own repository as a remote with a corresponding branch name, then git would preserve timestamps of the files and be able to merge the differences correctly.